# How to setup and use Firebase cloud function emulator: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?authuser=0&hl=en) instructs me to get a firebase project started, get an app started, and install firebase tools.  I've done it, and with the code on the page that begins...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

The trigger function suggested on that page, that starts like this...

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
      .onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

...works great. On that very same page, it shows me how to "Connect your app to emulators", with the recommended code like this...

```
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

// firebaseApps previously initialized using initializeApp()
const db = getFirestore();
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);
```

But this code uses the module style and, the emulator code I started in the background errors out saying:

> import  "firebase/functions"; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Why did the doc (on the very same page) instruct me to use two incompatible syntax styles?  I figure the more modern (module) style is better, and a little googling led me to understand that I can upgrade my functions/index.js to a module by saying this in package.json:

```
  // stuff before this
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
  // stuff after this
```

After that, the original require doesn't work, but more googling, and *I think* I can change it to this....

```
//const functions = require("firebase-functions");
import  "firebase/functions";
```

Is that right so far? I hope so, but now the console error from the emulator says this:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created
>
> - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
>   at getApp (file:///yada/yada/functions/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:469:29)

I just want to try out some cloud functions. How do I get it working?  Here's my whole, not-working functions/index.js...

```
//const functions = require("firebase-functions");
import  "firebase/functions";

import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import { doc, collection, setDoc, deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// firebaseApps previously initialized using initializeApp()
const db = getFirestore();
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);


exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const original = snap.data().original;
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
    });

exports.onMyCollectionWrite = functions.firestore.document('/collectionA/{docId}/subcollection/{subDocId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

    // here, I want to use things like:
    // const promise = setDoc(collection(db, 'someCollection','someId), { someKey: 'some value' });
    // return promise.then(() => console.log('done'));

    });
```

I also hope to learn how I'll need to change this file once it's ready to be deployed to work on the real database.

Comment: Why are you using the client SDK in a Cloud function? You can use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll receive that error as you're missing Firebase App Initialization. You should initialize using this code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

You can get the config by navigating to your Firebase Project Settings > Your Apps > SDK setup and configuration. You could also check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for more information. ***

You're just importing your configuration here if ever you want to work with your real database.

---

> Note: When connecting to the Cloud Firestore emulator from any other
> environment, you will need to specify a project ID. You can pass a
> project ID to initializeApp directly or set the GCLOUD_PROJECT
> environment variable. Note that you do not need to use your real
> Firebase project ID; the Cloud Firestore emulator will accept any
> project ID, as long as it has a valid format. You can find more
> information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore?hl=en&authuser=0#admin_sdks).

---

Also, I just want to point out that you're still mixing two different syntax which is the v9 (modular) and v8 (namespaced). You'll still receive an error after fixing the `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created`. The error should be like this:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
```

If you plan to use the modular version then you also should change how you export your functions. See sample code below:

```
export const makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const original = snap.data().original;
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

Here's a full sample code of which you could use all the Firebase emulator:

```
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = {
// your-config
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
const storage = getStorage();
const functions = getFunctions(getApp());

// Do this to check whether you're on an emulator or not. (Only if you're on the frontend side)
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}

export const functionName = async () => {
  // do something
};
```

---

Here's some documentation that you can start with:

> - [Connect your app to the Authentication Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth)
> - [Connect your app to the Realtime Database Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb)
> - [Connect your app to the Cloud Firestore Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore)
> - [Connect your app to the Cloud Storage Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage)
> - [Connect your app to the Cloud Functions Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions)
> - [Add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

---

Note: If you plan to use the modular version then make sure to check Web Version 9 from the documentation as you would encounter issues when you use Web Version 8.

If you're still unsure what to use, then I would suggest using the compat versions as you can use namespace and modular version with the same import. You check it out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

---

Update:

The above codes are for guide purposes only which shows how you can connect to the emulator, I also added some notes regarding the `firebaseConfig` above. For your use-case, you should only be using Firestore and Functions emulator. See sample code below:

```
const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
const db = getFirestore();
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);

export const makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const original = snap.data().original;
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused about running cloud functions.  The suggestion you make using a big config object, I thought, was what clients say to make a connection. Saying something like `window.hostname` also seems wrong in a file defining cloud functions.  Can you explain?

Comment: Hi @goodson , I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just to add. By removing the `connectFunctionsEmulator` and `connectFirestoreEmulator`, you'll be able to work with your real database as it is initialized on your `firebaseConfig`, vice versa.

Comment: The `const functions = getFunctions()` is a [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/functions.functions.md#functions_interface) instance and does not have any `.firestore` property so there'll be a few more issues with this. You are supposed to import `functions` from  `firebase-functions` package to create Cloud functions. Also setting the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` env variable will make _Admin SDK_ to use emulators but the OP is using Client SDK.

Comment: Bu then, if we can deploy, we're deploying the imports of connectAuthEmulator, connectFirestoreEmulator, etc. How we can avoid this?